# How to calculate the sum of all columns based on a grouped variable and remove NA

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, sum

I am having a dataset where I would like to group by the ID variable and then calculate the sum of each column / variable. However, I am having some NA as you can see and I would like to remove them while the sum function is being excecuted as they return NA in some rows although some rows of the same ID contain values. I have tried to look around with no success and I have tried different methods again with no success. I would appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance.

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4),
              var1 = c(1, 2, 5, 10, NA, 5, 23, NA, NA, 1),
              var2 = c(1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 0, 1, 3, 23, 4))


data <- data %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
summarise(across(everything(), sum(., na.rm = T)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just the tilde `~` is missing:

```
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~sum(., na.rm = T)))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
     ID  var1  var2
* <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3     1
2     2    15     1
3     3    28     1
4     4     1    30
```

In case one `ID` group has only `NA` values you can do this:

```
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ifelse(all(is.na(.)), NA, sum(., na.rm = T))))
```

Comment: However if one ID group had only NAs in my data this code gives me 0 instead of NAs. How I am gonna code so that when there is at least one value it gives returns that value disregarding NAs but when there are only NAs it retun NA in that cell? Thank you

Comment: Have edited my answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Hi, yes it does. That is so helpful. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1):

We may specify the arguments of the function without using lambda function

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```